# how to call static method inside non static method in c#

Tags: c#, .net, static-methods

how to call `static` method inside `non static` method in `c#` ?

Interviewer gave me  scenario :

```
class class1
{

    public static void method1(){}

    public void method2()
    {
        //call method1()
    }
```

How can we do it

Comment: What is the return type of method1?

Comment: Don't know why everyone is complaining about a return type, because it is not what this question is about. Sure it would need one, but it does not change the fundamentals of the question. Also I personally would use the class name, because it is more clear what's going on. `class1.method1();`

Comment: I was wondering if the OP was confusing a static constructor with a static method and thought that by asking the return type, I might unearth the intent

Comment: I have no idea why that would even be a question.  Given a properly-formatted class, you don't have to jump through any hoops to call a static member in an instanced object (as long as you avoid attempting to resolve through `this`).

Answer (score 12):

A normal practice is to call static method with class name.

See: [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/79b3xss3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The **static member is always accessed by the class name**, not the
>   instance name. Only one copy of a static member exists, regardless of
>   how many instances of the class are created.

So your call would be like:

```
class1.method1();
```

But it is **not necessary**

You can call the static method without class name like:

```
method1();
```

But you can only do that inside the class which holds that static method, you can't call static method without class name outside of that class.

Answer (score 4):

if you call the method in  the some class you just call it like this

```
    public void method2()
    {
        method1();  

    }
```

but if it should been called from another class you  have to precede it with the name of the class

```
public void method2()
        {
            class1.method1();  

        }
```

Comment: method1 needs a return type for it to compile.

Answer (score 4):

```
class1.method1();
```

Same as you'd call any other static method

Apparently (as Selman22 pointed out) - the classname isn't necessary.

So

```
method1();
```

would work just as well

Comment: Who said the class name is **necessary** ??

Comment: Oh, it's actually not necessary to add the class name, but it'll work either way

Comment: okey,just note that :) he/she might think the class name is necessary  OP just forgot to write the return type of static method  thus it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

You type the method name out, and then compile and run it:

```
class class1
{
    public static void method1(){}

    public void method2()
    {
        method1()
    }
}
```

Comment: Curious, what would be the difference between calling `method1()` vs `class1.method1()`? Shouldn't be any difference, since it' static, I'm just wondering why you wouldn't call it statically from the class reference?

Comment: @JoeBrunscheon There is no difference.  The type name can be omitted when calling the method from within the type itself.  It is inferred.

Comment: To the person who downvoted this answer, I assumed you don't realize that `class1` will simply be inferred here by the compiler, and that there is no need whatsoever to include it.

Comment: I know they are the same, but just wanted to hear your thoughts on it.  Seems to me that it would come down to a programming style guideline more than anything else on whether or not you call the static method by class name or just method name.

Comment: @JoeBrunscheon Sure, just like you have the option to explicitly include `this.` before all instance fields/methods as well, even though the compiler will infer that.  It's personal preference.

Comment: Agreed. As I said, I was just curious as to your interpretation / reasoning on this. I don't often mix Static and Non-static methods in Non-static classes.

Comment: @JoeBrunscheon As with most anything else that can be inferred, by default I allow the compiler to infer whatever it can unless I have some compelling reason not to.  If, for example, there was a static and non-static method of the same name in the same class, I'd likely be more explicit, but if I felt there was no cause for confusion as to the fact that the method is static, I wouldn't bother being so explicit.